# imshow images are too small

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I am training an denoising network and the code for it is given below

```
res = degraded.copy()
j = 0
for i in range(30):
    res = denoiser.denoise(res/255.0)*255
    print("Iter:", i, "PSNR noisy:", cal_psnr(res, gt))
    if i%10==0:
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
        ax = plt.subplot(20,4,2+j)
        plt.imshow(np.squeeze(np.clip(res / 255 ,0,1)), cmap="gray")
        plt.title('Iteration ' +str(i))
        ax = plt.subplot(20,4,6+j)
        plt.imshow(np.squeeze(np.clip(np.abs(res-degraded)/10.0,0,1)))
        #plt.title('Residual at iteration ' + str(i))
        j = j + 1
```

but i am getting images are small. I think their is a mistake in assigning `plt.subplot` but unable to rectify it please help

[image]

How i need the images to be:
[image]

Comment: `plt.subplot(20,4,6+j)` You're plotting `20 * 4 = 80` images in one figure. So, it's no surprise that you get tiny images. What do you actually want? Larger images in your plot figure, having maybe less images per figure? Or, are you afraid, that the actual, underlying images are that small? **They're not!** That's just a visualization thing.

Comment: @HansHirse so how can i visualize without making them small. I am denoising an image and outputting image every 10 epochs. visualizing the image big is important for me to understand whether it is denoising or not

Comment: when visualizing 4 images every thing is fine after that i increased the epochs and tried to visualize them i got this problem. is their a way visualizing without making them small.

Comment: Please create a sketch or similar how your desired figure should look like, and put that into your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68209006/edit) it. Right now, it would be guessing. Do you actually need subplots? Is plotting the image of the current epoch sufficient? Etc.

Comment: @HansHirse I have updated please take a look

Comment: And how should it look like for 100 epochs? 25 "large" images next to each other? Replacing/updating the three/four images from left to right?

Comment: I may increase the epochs if needed , is their anyway plotting the image without using subplot. i don't need the images to be as a grid. if they are in the big size and recursively displaying in an order is enough

Comment: For each **iteration** (4-fold, 10-fold) create a new figure `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))`. Inside the loop use `ax = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)` for the first and `ax = plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)` for the second image. You'll get one figure with the two images next to each other for each iteration.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. can you explain what j is doing in the code i shared, why they are doing `j+=1`  in subplot

Comment: @HansHirse i am facing this error `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:10: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
  # Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.`.  and i am not getting output

Comment: @HansHirse Every thing is fine when i am plotting 1st image, but when i am plotting my 2nd image then i am facing this problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234414/discussion-between-harsha-and-hanshirse).